# como fazer consulta por Mês?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, select

Na tabela do BD tenho uma coluna "dia" tipo "date" guardando "yyyy-mm-dd", estou tentando fazer uma consulta que me retorne o mês atual,
já tentei de varias formas e nada.

`<?php session_start();
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    $d = date('d');
    $m = date('m');
    $y = date('Y');
    $query_cx = "SELECT dia FROM caixa WHERE MONTH(data)='$m' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result_cx = mysqli_query($conectar, $query_cx);
    while ($linhas_cx = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_cx)){
       echo "$linhas_cx['valor'];
    }
?>`

a segunda parte são duvidas, pensando que o ano esta acabando e que essa consulta sempre vai me retornar o mês atual;

1- essa consulta vai acabar me retornando o Mês atual e o mesmo mês do ano anterior?

2- como eu faria pra pesquisar algum Mês anterior, se o ano vai ser diferente?

Comment: 1. O que seria esse "nada" ? Um erro.. não retorna dados.. causa alguma exceção inesperada....

Resposta pra 1. Sim, ela retornará para aquele mês em específico.. não verificando o ano.

Resposta para 2. Na pesquisa adicione a seleção do ano para pesquisa.

Answer (score 0):

> (sic) estou tentando fazer uma consulta que me retorne o mês atual

**Solução** (presumindo que seu db seja *MySQL ou MariaDB*):

```
SELECT `dia` FROM `caixa` WHERE `data` >= '2018-12-01' AND `data` <= '2018-12-31';
```

No *PHP* você só vai precisar substituir o mês na *query*, ficando assim (seguindo seu exemplo):

```
<?php session_start();
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    //$d = date('d');
    //$m = date('m');
    //$y = date('Y');
    //$query_cx = "SELECT dia FROM caixa WHERE MONTH(data)='$m' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $query_cx = "SELECT `dia` FROM `caixa` WHERE `data` >= '".date('Y-m')."-01' AND `data` <= '".date('Y-m')."-31';";
    $result_cx = mysqli_query($conectar, $query_cx);
    while ($linhas_cx = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_cx)){
       // echo "$linhas_cx['valor']; // PQ USAR ASPAS AQUI (e ainda falta fechar)?
       echo $linhas_cx['valor'];
    }
```

> 1- essa consulta vai acabar me retornando o Mês atual e o mesmo mês do ano anterior?

Não, pois declaramos o ano na consulta.

> 2- como eu faria pra pesquisar algum Mês anterior, se o ano vai ser diferente?

Basta alterar a *query*:

```
$query_cx = "SELECT `dia` FROM `caixa` WHERE `data` >= '".date('Y-m', strtotime('-1 month'))."-01' AND `data` <= '".date('Y-m', strtotime('-1 month'))."-31';";
```

**Leitura recomendada**:

> [Manipulando datas com PHP](https://www.devmedia.com.br/manipulando-datas-com-php/32966)

Answer (score 0):

Um jeito simples de fazer isso é utilizando apenas o próprio sql

```
SELECT dia FROM caixa WHERE MONTH(data)= MONTH(NOW()) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Dessa forma vai retornar conteúdo dos anos anteriores, já que não é mencionado o ano na consulta.